# OpenGL won't draw a triangle, followed exact format

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

I was able to get to the point where it creates a window and everything is fine, but when I attempt to make a Triangle, it wouldn't show up.

I've created a buffer and bind it and also made my shader, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work.

I am using MacOSX and Xcode.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

//GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;


static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile" << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);


    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;


}

int main(void)
{
    //glfwInit();


    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

    GLFWwindow * window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, & screenHeight);

    if (!window)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();

        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
    {
        cout << "Failed to Initialize Glew" << endl;

        return -1;
    }

    glViewport ( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    //vertex buffer

    float positions[6] = {
       -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };


    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (6 * sizeof(float)), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (sizeof(float)*2), 0);


    std::string vertexShader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "   layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose ( window ))
    {

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3F, 0.3, 1.0f);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwTerminate( );
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: A revision-1 MCVE in [tag:opengl]?!  It's an April miracle!

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Call `glfwInit()` before calling `glfwWindowHint()`.  Otherwise it won't have any effect and you'll (probably) end up with [a Compatibility context instead of the Core context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_3.2_and_Profiles) you were asking for.

   If you set [an error callback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling):

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       glfwSetErrorCallback( []( int, const char* str )
       {
           std::cerr << "GLFW error: " << str << std::endl;
       });

       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

       if (!glfwInit())
           return -1;
   ...
   ```

   ...you can see GLFW error stream caused by calling [(most)](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#intro_init) GLFW functions before `glfwInit()`:

   ```
   GLFW error: The GLFW library is not initialized
   GLFW error: The GLFW library is not initialized
   GLFW error: The GLFW library is not initialized
   GLFW error: The GLFW library is not initialized
   GLFW error: The GLFW library is not initialized
   ```
2. [Vertex Array Objects (VAOs)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) aren't optional in Core contexts.

   Create & bind a VAO before trying to enable/set vertex attributes & drawing:

   ```
   ...
   GLuint vao = 0;
   glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
   glBindVertexArray( vao );

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   ...
   ```

All together:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

//GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;


static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile" << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);


    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;


}

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

    GLFWwindow * window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, & screenHeight);

    if (!window)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();

        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
    {
        cout << "Failed to Initialize Glew" << endl;

        return -1;
    }

    glViewport ( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    //vertex buffer

    float positions[6] = {
       -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };


    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (6 * sizeof(float)), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (sizeof(float)*2), 0);


    std::string vertexShader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "   layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose ( window ))
    {

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3F, 0.3, 1.0f);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwTerminate( );
    return 0;
}
```